# One thread to send data another to fetch data at certain time interval

Tags: multithreading, web-services, heap-memory

I am working on a webservice in java where I have to store the fetched data from db and send that data at every request but i want to store this data in memory instead of making repeated calls to db

And make another thread that after every 10min fetches new data from db and save in memory.is it possible

Comment: Take a look into using a cache; e.g. memcached.

Comment: I cannot use memcached i have to do it using threads.is it possible to store data on heap memory while other thread is sleeping for say 10min as soon as the 10min over the thread updates the data and go back to sleep again

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's just hard to get it right. For starters, you can use a ReadWriteLock, readers hold the read-lock before reading and the writer thread holds write-lock before it is ready to update.

Comment: An example would be helpful